# Huge Buttons with Simple Donate

Tags: simple-donate-form

I tried simple donate extension on my Civi 4.6/Wordpress/Stripe install to mix things up.  It seems that the buttons are way too large for some reason.  Anyone have a suggestion on fixing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With a default-ish theme, the SimpleDonate extension intends to make the form elements bigger and more clicky. In this case that has not worked out - possibly because of other styles introduced by your theme or other plugins.

However: **those button styles you're seeing are coming from the SimpleDonate extension**. And that's OK - you can address this by overriding with your own theme's CSS. Even just adding a style which cleared the buttons into rows of three would improve what you're seeing.

The liberal use of `!important` in [SimpleDonate's CSS](https://github.com/webaccess/com.webaccessglobal.simpledonate/blob/master/css/simpledonate.css) may be a sticking point when overriding the extension's builtin styles. If I had to make that CSS work, the first thing I'd do would be replace every instance of `!important` with an appropriate CSS selector (and submit the PR back to SimpleDonate).

Answer (score 1):

Best talk to your WordPress "theme" author, as this is ultimately down to that (though any coder could probably help).

If this is a default theme that ships with WordPress then you should log a bug on the extension's GitHub page here: https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/issues

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I'll assume that it's more a Simple Donate extension issue as the stripe plug-in works normally otherwise.   It appears the donation amounts are also all mixed up too... odd